# How could I pass JSON object array result to my api URL? (In REACT)

Tags: json, reactjs, api, object, response

I have to fetch 2 api from backend, and try to get the result from this two. but, at the moment, the JSON result I get from the first API is object Array in JSON. I need to pass the id from first API(using setState) to second API for path variables. But when I do in my way, it fail to retrieve the data. Consider the code below:

```
      componentDidMount(){
        // console.log(loginEmail)
          fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/list`,)
          .then((resp)=>{
            resp.json().then((res)=>{
             console.log(res.data);
             // localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
              this.setState({data: res.data});
            
            }
              
            )
          })

          const id = this.state.data.id;

          fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${id}`,)
          .then((resp)=>{
            resp.json().then((res)=>{
             console.log(res);
             // localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
              this.setState({res});}
            )
          })
        
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fetch returns a `Promise` so, at the line

```
const id = this.state.data.id;
```

You do not have data populated yet.

You have to concatenate the two requests in a way like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/list`)
    .then((resp) => {
      // return the id
    })
    .then((id) => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${id}`)
        .then((resp) => {
         // do what you need with the result
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is asynchronous, which means javascript will
fetch data on the first call with no waiting, and continue
to the second fetch call where the id is not defined or Null.

In order to fix that you can use promises as follow

My code example

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      res: [],
    }
  }

// http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
fetchData(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url)
          .then((resp) => {
              resp.json().then((res) => {
                  console.log(res);
                  // localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
                  resolve(res);
              }
              )
          })
  })
}

async componentDidMount() {
  let data = await this.fetchData("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  console.log("data :", data);
  let id = data[0].id;
  console.log("Id :", id);
  let newData = await this.fetchData(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`); 
  this.setState({ res: newData });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Call API
      </div>      
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Adapted on your code

```
fetchData(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => {
                resp.json().then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    // localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.user_info.id);
                    resolve(res.data);
                }
                )
            })
    })
}

async componentDidMount() {
    // console.log(loginEmail)
    let data = await this.fetchData("http://localhost:9000/api/item/list");
    let id = data.id;
    let newData = await this.fetchData(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${id}`); 
    this.setState({ res: newData });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that each id gets its relevant results.

```
 async componentDidMount() {
 await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/list`)
.then(async (resp) => {
  let req_ = resp.map((item)=>{
   return await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${item.id}`)
  })
 let result = Promise.all(req_)
 console.log(result)
})
}
```